# How to troubleshoot my unstable wireless connection?

Tags: wireless, connection

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and I use a D-Link DWA-110 USB device for receiving signal form my router. My connection drops down after a while (sometimes minutes, sometimes hours). It seems to be connected to network, but the usb device just stops working.

I discarded ISP and router issues because my other desktop computer, with the same features but different wireless device, works perfectly.

Following this: [help.ubuntu.com Wireless Trouble Shooting Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers) (I'm almost sure it is a driver issue), I got this:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network 
 *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 01
   serial: 40:61:86:50:8f:d7
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:42 ioport:ce00(size=256) memory:fd9ff000-fd9fffff memory:fda00000-fda1ffff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@1:2
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: 00:1e:58:99:4a:51
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt73usb driverversion=3.0.0-14-generic-pae firmware=1.7 ip=192.168.0.2 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

As you can see, my driver is rt73usb. This is what I got with lsmod:

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 38408  0 
bnep                   17923  2 
bluetooth             148839  10 rfcomm,bnep
parport_pc             32114  0 
ppdev                  12849  0 
binfmt_misc            17292  1 
arc4                   12473  2 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   254125  1 
rt73usb                27029  0 
crc_itu_t              12627  1 rt73usb
rt2x00usb              20092  1 rt73usb
rt2x00lib              48114  2 rt73usb,rt2x00usb
mac80211              393459  2 rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib
cfg80211              172392  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
snd_hda_intel          28358  2 
snd_hda_codec          91754  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80435  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25241  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51567  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
usb_storage            44173  0 
snd_timer              28932  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
uas                    17699  0 
snd                    55902  13
snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
usbhid                 41905  0 
hid                    77367  1 usbhid
i915                  509290  3 
drm_kms_helper         32889  1 i915
drm                   196290  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
video                  18908  1 i915
soundcore              12600  1 snd
psmouse                63474  0 
snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
serio_raw              12990  0 
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
r8169                  47200  0
```

I don't know what this line means:

```
$rt73usb                27029  0
```

but it doesn't look good for me.

Please, help me. I love Ubuntu, and this is the only ploblem I have with it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you still looking for help with this or did you solve the problem? If you did find an answer please consider adding it here, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue reported. It's an open bug since 11.04 . The problem stands in the newer Ubuntu version, 12.04 . Here there are a good description about the problem:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsDlink

"Connection speed average is slow and fluctuates. Reported conflicts with driver rt2500. Windows drivers solve the fluctuation, but there are eventual system freezing with ndiswrapper."